# How to make parallax effect in image tag without background image?

Tags: html, css

I tried to make that with background-image css.
it is working well.

```
*{background-attached:fixed}*
```

but I need to make this in  tag.

```
*<img src='image url'>*
```

I want to make parallax effect with css.
is there way to solve this?
please help me.

Comment: Is this homework? Why can't you use what you know works? Also: `<img>` tags can have css backgrounds too, just like any other tag. They just won't be visible unless the image has transparent area.

Comment: As long as I'm understanding you correctly: the answer is no; you can't get `background-fixed` behaviour from an image element rendered by `<img src="..">` using CSS alone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest parallax implementation, and its a combination of CSS and HTML tags not just a backgrond image, check this [tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_parallax.asp) which I referenced here:

```css
.parallax {
  /* The image used */
  background-image: url("https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_parallax.jpg");

  /* Set a specific height */
  min-height: 500px; 

  /* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>

</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Scroll Up and Down this page to see the parallax scrolling effect.</p>

<div class="parallax"></div>

<div style="height:1000px;background-color:red;font-size:36px">
Scroll Up and Down this page to see the parallax scrolling effect.
This div is just here to enable scrolling.
Tip: Try to remove the background-attachment property to remove the scrolling effect.
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**update**: this snippet based on this [tutorial](https://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/)

```css
 /* Parallax base styles
  --------------------------------------------- */

  .parallax {
    height: 100vh;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    -webkit-perspective: 1px;
    perspective: 1px;
  }

  .parallax__layer {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
  }

  .parallax__layer--base {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    transform: translateZ(0);
  }

  .parallax__layer--back {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
    transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
  }


  /* demo styles
  --------------------------------------------- */

  * {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
  }

  body {
    font: 100% / 1.5 Arial;
  }

  .parallax {
    font-size: 200%;
  }

   /* add some padding to force scrollbars */
  .parallax__layer {
    padding: 100vh 0;
  }

   /* centre the content in the parallax layers */
  .title {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
  img {
      width: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      transform: translateZ(-10px);
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="parallax">
    <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--back">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_parallax.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--base">
      <div class="title">This is the foreground</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks but I want to make the parallax effect in <img> tag. not background-image

Comment: Ok sorry, missed it since its not clear from the question! will check ti later if I have time and update my answer.

Comment: @bbwstar I updated my answer, check the new snippet.

Comment: Not a good idea to plagiarize https://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/

Comment: @j08691 you are right, I will add the source here too!

Comment: The first snippet is not an example of parallax, just a fixed background.

Comment: @TylerH, sure it is, but does it make a different if its same as a design given? I'm trying to know the pros and cons here if its bad as implementation.

Comment: @Ma'mounothman I'm not sure what "sure it is" in response to, but parallax is the difference in motion along a similar axis between two objects relative to an observer at a 3rd point. If one of the two objects (such as background here) is not moving at all in relation to the observer (the user), then there's no observable parallax effect. For the record, the second example does show a parallax effect, because both the foreground and background are moving along a similar axis, but at different speeds.

Comment: @TylerH, I meant that its a fixed background as you said, and thanks for clarification!

Comment: @TylerH I understand the distinction that you're making between fixed and parallax, but I think one could reasonably argue that it is still, by definition, an example of parallax scrolling. Albeit a basic/boring example, but the foreground content *is* moving at a different speed than the background image. In fact, if you search "parallax CSS" the first result (at the time of writing) is w3schools "How TO - Parallax Scrolling" page which provides 4 examples, all of which demonstrate the effect using fixed background scrolling (not that w3schools should be the authority on the matter).